# Is it acceptable to provide links to a "do my homework for money" site?

Tags: discussion, external-links, homework

I just came across a question which was an obvious "homework dump".  Someone commented (appropriately) to the effect that we don't do peoples' homework here.  But they also added a link to a site that purports to do people's homework for them for money.

Should we condone this kind of linking?

- Should we be encouraging students to cheat (themselves mostly!) by not doing their own homework?
- Should we support sites with this kind of dubious business model by linking to them?

I considered just raising a moderator flag for the comment, but I would like to hear the community's views on this.

Comment: A comment should ask for clarification of the post. Redirection to other services isn't a clarification. Flag the comment as no longer needed, down vote the question, cast a close vote for needs focus, maybe post a cv-pls in SOCVR to make sure it gets closed, move on.

Comment: A "no longer needed" flag on that comment (or others like it) is sufficient.

Comment: Well, since these 'homework sites' are often scams, and often just repost tbe questions to SO, I would delete all such links immediately.  I suspect thet these 'homework factors' are a substantial reason that new use....accounts do not reply to commented requests for question clarification, (because they have no clue about the question they posted), and then get triggered if their payday is not immediately enabled by the drone army of SO slaves:(

Comment: I think this is similar to the LMGTFY-problem. I assume that when someone links to a homework service then the intention is to let the OP know his question is not for SO in a very expressive way. I think just telling the OP that SO is not a homework service is enough; no need to be "rude" like that.

Comment: @akuzminykh - That may be the case.  However lmgify is merely "rude".  Linking to a homework site is "rude" plus 1) supporting an unethical site, and 2) putting the OP at risk of being scammed.  One problem is that the OP may not realize that the commenter is being rude to them ...

Comment: @StephenC Yes, I fully agree. Those reasons just add to the fact that such comments don't help the OP or SO. It would just add a weird facet to the whole SO character, when new users get responses like that by the community. And actively harmful links are obviously the worst case.

Comment: "Should we be encouraging students to cheat" - Nope, that is not what Stack Overflow is for. If people want to pay to have their homework done, Google and Bing are <--- that way.

Answer (score 19):

Based on the comments, I think that the consensus is that such links should not be tolerated because:

- They can be interpreted as rude.  (Indeed, they could well be *intended* as a put down, though it is difficult to know for sure what someone's real intentions are.)
- They are liable to send customers to a site with a business model that we (at least the majority of us) do not approve of.
- They potentially open up the user to being scammed.

Cody Gray assures us that flagging as "no longer needed" is appropriate and that flags will be dealt with.

Answer (score 6):

It isn't useful to comment a link that takes the OP somewhere which offers a service to solve their problem. If that were the case, then sending people to somewhere like elance would be the answer to every question starting with "how do I".

These comments also border on the "maybe you should hire a developer!" aspect of passive aggressive response, so we really don't need them around.

Flagging these as no longer needed is definitely appropriate.

However, it is important to only flag these as you find them, setting up a sql query and mass flagging will lead to an undue burden on the moderation team. If you feel there is a way to mass flag a link, then write up a meta question indicating the need for that so it can be added to the regex that removes comments from 1 flag.